# Issue in iterating MongoCursor using foreach loop with php

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to iterate the MongoCursor using the foreach loop as shown in the code below. The loop only returns the first record. Can anyone figure out what the issue is?

Here is my code

```
$usrcollection = $db->users;
$user = new MongoId($userid);
$where = array('_id' => $user);
$filter = array('courses.coursename' =>true, 'courses.startdate' => true,'courses.duration' =>  true, 'courses.status' => true,'courses.completed' => true,'courses.institute' => true,'courses.instructor' => true,'courses.coursecreated' => true,  '_id' => 0);
$usercursor = $usrcollection->find($where,$filter);

$j = 0; 
foreach ($usercursor as $value) {
    echo($value['courses'][$j]['coursename']);      
    $j++;
}
```

The output of print_r is

```
Array ( [courses] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [coursename] => Machine learning [startdate] => 2013-12-01 [duration] => 12 Weeks [institute] => Standford University [instructor] => Dr Lafore [status] => Inprogress [completed] => 20 [coursecreated] => MongoDate Object ( [sec] => 1386751059 [usec] => 0 ) ) [1] => Array ( [coursename] => Fashion Design [startdate] => 2013-12-10 [duration] => 3 Weeks [institute] => MIT [instructor] => Ebay [status] => Inprogress [completed] => 0 [coursecreated] => MongoDate Object ( [sec] => 1386753755 [usec] => 0 ) ) ) )
```

The MongoDb schema is below

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("52972705f770dff815000002"),
 "badge": "Gold",
 "badgecount": NumberInt(3),
 "badgedate": ISODate("2013-11-13T05:53:49.0Z"),
 "badges": {
 "0": {
   "badgename": "Silver",
   "achievedon": ISODate("2013-10-05T05:53:49.0Z")
  },
 "1": {
   "badgename": "Gold",
   "achievedon": ISODate("2013-11-13T05:53:49.0Z")
  }
 },
"courses": {
 "0": {
   "coursename": "Machine learning",
   "startdate": "2013-12-01",
   "duration": "12 Weeks",
   "institute": "Standford University",
   "instructor": "Dr Lafore ",
   "status": "Inprogress",
   "completed": "20",
   "coursecreated": ISODate("2013-12-11T08:37:39.0Z")
   },
  "1": {
   "coursename": "Fashion Design",
   "startdate": "2013-12-10",
   "duration": "3 Weeks",
   "institute": "MIT",
   "instructor": "Ebay",
   "status": "Inprogress",
   "completed": NumberInt(0),
   "coursecreated": ISODate("2013-12-11T09:22:35.0Z")
  }
 },
 "datejoined": ISODate("2013-10-01T05:53:49.0Z"),
 "education": {
  "0": "Msc Computer science"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
foreach ($usercursor as $value) {
  for($i = 0; $i < count($value['courses']); $i++) {
       echo($value['courses'][$i]['coursename']);    
  }
}
```

The problem is that find() returns a pointer, not a result. The foreach that you are iterating just fetches all to rows and to do what you want you need another loop.

Comment: Ok, check you question as answered so ppl know that it`s answered :)